# javascript - rails upvoting without act_as_votable gem and no refresh to update

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have my *Tip* model where any user can upvote or downvote, and Vrecord where I keep the vote logs. I also have *Game* model where users can add their tips to.

On my *Vrecord*, a column includes **tip_id** and **pos** that have "u" or "d" variable to tell if its an upvote or downvote so I can limit their vote on each per IP. If there is a "u", it wont allow the IP to upvote anymore, but if it downvotes, it will delete the "u", vice-versa.

I didn't use act_as_votable gem and I knew I should have. I made this voting system as I am learning ruby. Its really messy, but please have a look.

```
def upvote
    t = Tip.find(params[:id]) 
    gm = Game.find(v.game_id)
    ip = request.ip
    unless Vrecord.exists?(:ip => ip, :tip_id => t.id, :pos => "u")
      Tip.increment_counter(:votes, t.id)
      if Vrecord.exists?(:ip => ip, :tip_id => t.id, :pos => "d")
        rec = Vrecord.where(:ip => ip, :tip_id => t.id, :pos => "d")
        rec.delete(rec.ids)
      end
      @vrecord = Vrecord.new(:ip => ip, :tip_id => t.id, :pos => "u")
      @vrecord.save      
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to champion_path(ch, anchor:'countertip') }
    end
  end
```

The downvote looks pretty much the same. I refresh the page after voting. But I want it to update by itself without refreshing, which calls for javascript and I am basically clueless where to start. I have tried searching but I've been unsuccessful mostly because the answers I saw use act_as_votable gem.

This is a part of my tip table on view:

```
<% @tips.limit(5).order('votes DESC').each do |tip| %>
<td id = "votebox">
        <div><%= link_to image_tag('', class: "uparrow"), tip_upvote_path(tip, :id => tip.id), method: :put, class: "tip_upvote" %></div>
        <div><%= link_to image_tag('', class: "downarrow"), tip_downvote_path(tip, :id => tip.id), method: :put, class: "tip_downvote" %></div>
</td>
<td class="vote_count"><%= tip.votes %></td>
<% end %>
```

What I know is I have to put remote: true on the link_to, add render format.js on my upvote function in the controller, and make an upvote.js.erb. How do I go about the javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your view(html.erb) code where you show the upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: @GokulM Updated. Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `remote: true` to the links and `id` to the vote count `td`:

```
<% @tips.limit(5).order('votes DESC').each do |tip| %>
<td id = "votebox">
    <div><%= link_to image_tag('', class: "uparrow"), tip_upvote_path(tip, :id => tip.id), remote: true, method: :put, class: "tip_upvote" %></div>
    <div><%= link_to image_tag('', class: "downarrow"), tip_downvote_path(tip, :id => tip.id), remote: true, method: :put, class: "tip_downvote" %></div>
</td>
<td class="vote_count" id="vote-count-<%= tip.id %>"><%= tip.votes %></td>
<% end %>
```

Create **upvote.js.erb** with the code to update the vote count:

```
$('#vote-count-<%= @tip.id %>').text("<%= @tip.votes %>")
```

Controller **upvote** action:

```
  def upvote
    @tip = Tip.find(params[:id]) 
    gm = Game.find(v.game_id)
    ip = request.ip
    unless Vrecord.exists?(:ip => ip, :tip_id => @tip.id, :pos => "u")
      Tip.increment_counter(:votes, @tip.id)
      if Vrecord.exists?(:ip => ip, :tip_id => @tip.id, :pos => "d")
        rec = Vrecord.where(:ip => ip, :tip_id => @tip.id, :pos => "d")
        rec.delete(rec.ids)
      end
      @vrecord = Vrecord.new(:ip => ip, :tip_id => @tip.id, :pos => "u")
      @vrecord.save      
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

That's it.

Comment: thank you! Its kind of working now, but I ran to another problem. When I click upvote, it wont do anything, but if I click it the second time, it changes and works. i also tried clicking one time and refreshing the page, and the increment adds up.

Comment: Can you change the `@tip.votes` to `@tip.reload.votes` in the **upvote.js.erb** file and check?